# GPO applied to server when logged on with a local ID

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have servers in my domain, and have GPOs created for it. Question is if I log on to the server using the server's local ID and not the domain ID, will the GPO still be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Question is if I log on to the server using the server's local ID and not the domain ID, will the GPO still be applied?`

Yes. Any GPO's that configure Computer Configuration settings will be applied whether you log on with a local user account or a domain user account.